# Azure Application gateway integration with apim in two different vnets

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

I have an app gateway in region A with listeners set up for apim backend both in the same vnet. I want to create another app gateway in region B in a different vnet and a listener for same apim backend in region A(using internal virtual ip). I have vnet peered the two vnets but the backend health pool for app agteway in region B  does not recognize the private ip of apim in region A

Answer (score 0):

The Basic Load Balancers doesn't work in the global VNet peering. See [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview#:%7E:text=Some%20services%20that%20use%20a%20Basic%20load%20balancer%20don%27t%20work%20over%20global%20virtual%20network%20peering).

Unfortunately, [APIM is one of the services which uses the basic load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-faq#what-are-the-constraints-related-to-global-vnet-peering-and-load-balancers#:%7E:text=API%20Management).

So network peering won't work for your case. You would have to use VNet gateways to facilitate the vnet-to-vnet communication in this case.